# How Can I Improve the Performance of a Heroku-hosted Application with a European User Base?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, heroku, amazon-web-services

I have a Rails 3.2 application hosted by Heroku. I am based in the UK and most of the application's users are based in Europe. Currently the performance leaves a lot to be desired, given that the app is located in the American region.

**Is there anything I can do to improve performance for European users whilst still hosting with Heroku, or do I need to look for an alternative host based in the European region?**

Edit: The problem is not the app. It's the delay between requesting a page and the request hitting the app.

Comment: Did you profile your application? Are you sure that the performance issues stem from network delays and are not caused by other factors?

Comment: You might want to look for alternatives to heroku if you need hosting in Europe. As @Mchl wrote, check what is actually the performance bottleneck. If it is the server placement, you might want to look into  [appfog](https://www.appfog.com/product/) as an alternative.

Comment: @Mchl Yep definitely lag before it even hits Heroku.

Comment: With web apps, it can sometimes be the web html response that takes a long time, and sometimes the assets. How long is the lag for the HTML and how long for the assets? You may be able to make the assets load fast if the HTML load is acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of yesterday (2013-04-24) The simple answer to this question is `heroku create --region eu`

Read more on the blog: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/4/24/europe-region

To migrate an existing app: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-migration#fork-application

Answer (score 0):

If you're on the free stack then use this tip to prevent your dyno from idling and spinning down (and having to spin back up):

[Easy way to prevent Heroku idling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480337/easy-way-to-prevent-heroku-idling)

Find out which pages are having the most negative impact on performance and see if you can use any of these caching strategies to lighten the load:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/caching-strategies

Identify processes that could be run in the background so you can return requests faster. Resque and Redis for that:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/queuing-ruby-resque

Comment: As I mention in my question, the problem is not the app, but the distance. Whilst all these suggestions are valid, they are generic and not related to my particular situation. I have 2 Web dynos, already use Sidekiq and use caching wherever appropriate.

Comment: I can't think of anything that would solve the "distance" problem except performance tuning your app or moving to a host in Europe.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at:

- reduce page size / number of objects - doesn't matter how fast you make the site, if the pages are huge
- add a CDN - moving static content closer to the user dramatically improves the performance for those assets (how much it impacts your site, depends on how much static data you have)
- various other performance tweaks from yslow or similar
- anycast DNS - a decent DNS service can make a minor but noticeable difference

I spent some time optimising my site on Octopress/Heroku, and wrote it up (http://www.damon.io/blog/2013/01/10/improving-octopress-jekyll-site-performance-DNS-hosting-CDN/) there's some comparisons for some CDNs and DNS which you may find interesting.

Of course, how relevant this is to your site, I can't say, but hopefully there's something useful in here for you.