# Heroku idling with 2 dynos

Tags: heroku

I've 2 dynos for my Java web app on herkou. 
As per the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-idling), it should not idle if I've more than 1 dyno.

From link above:
*"Apps that have more than 1 web dyno running are never idled out. Workers dynos are never idled out."*

My dyno still idles out. 
=== web (2X): `xxxxxxxxx.war`
web.1: idle 2013/06/11 04:31:46 (~ 2h ago)

Is there another setting that needs to be done so that the dyno is not idled?

I can try some approach as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480337/easy-way-to-prevent-heroku-idling). However, I'd like to understand if there's something missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That doesn't look like 2 dynos, that looks like a 2x (two times resources, CPU and memory) dyno ie the new one charged at $0.1 per hour and not 2 charged at $0.05.

Contrast your output to a 3 dyno output;

```
=== web (1X): `bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
web.1: up 2013/06/11 09:54:13 (~ 2h ago)
web.2: up 2013/06/11 09:54:27 (~ 2h ago)
web.3: up 2013/06/11 09:54:37 (~ 2h ago)
```

Comment: Just to confirm that this is expected behavior, the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-size) states "If your app has only a single 2X web dyno running, it will idle out."

Comment: @john-beynon you're right. I mistakenly took a "2x dyno" to be 2 dynos.