# Heroku free account, one-off dynos

Tags: heroku, scheduler

I've created an app on Heroku with one web dyno. If no traffic it will idle, thus take about 20 seconds to spin up on first visit.

If I add a Heroku Scheduler add-on to the app to prevent idling, what is the cost if it goes beyond the 750 free dyno hours?

Can I create a separate app (with another 750 free dyno hours), set the web dyno to zero and run the Heroku Scheduler add-on? 
Does this imply that I can process 750 dyno hours with the heroku scheduler add-on since no web dyno is set?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy way to prevent Heroku idling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480337/easy-way-to-prevent-heroku-idling)

Comment: I still wonder if it is possible to run the heroku scheduler add-on on a newly created app with 0 web dynos? Thus have 750 dyno hours of one-off dyno processing time. Don't think that was covered in [Easy way to prevent Heroku idling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480337/easy-way-to-prevent-heroku-idling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is yes you can. With the heroku scheduler add-on you don't need to run a web or worker dyno on that very same app. Only the scheduled job will consume dyno hours for that time it is running (doing the job) (and therefor you have the full amount of free dyno hours)).

> If I add a Heroku Scheduler add-on to the app to prevent idling, what is the cost if it goes beyond the 750 free dyno hours?

Then you pay for the dyno hours your app consumes. If your app consumes 751 dyno hours you pay 1 hour for example...