# Need help trying to keep Heroku awake (no idling)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

http://beouk.blogspot.ca/2012/02/keeping-heroku-awake.html

That is the tutorial I tried to follow, but it doesn't seem to work.
Here's what I did:

1. Add Heroku scheduler and add a job called "call_page" which runs hourly.
2. Created a file called 'scheduler.rake' in app/lib/tasks
3. Code in the file says:

desc "This task is called by the Heroku cron add-on"
task :call_page => :environment do
   uri = URI.parse('http://www.WEBSITE.com/')
   Net::HTTP.get(uri)
 end

But it's still not working. For website name, I'm using my registered domain name, and not the heroku subdomain. Could that be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Heroku dynos idle after 15 minutes so calling script every hour makes no sense.

Comment: Also, I have no idea what problem do you have, what's wrong with the script (any errors, etc)?

Comment: This topic has been discussed exhaustively. Have you considered Googling the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can create simple script which will perform any activity like visit your page every 10 minutes or so. You can use open-uri or even watir-webdriver for it. Than you put it into you crontab.

Simple, quick and dirty, but far from being elegant.

If it is acceptable in your case and you need some help to implement it, just ping me.

[All these dirty tricks are discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480337/easy-way-to-prevent-heroku-idling?rq=1)