# heroku work-in-progress app deployment

Tags: heroku

I'm looking for a free hosting to deploy my work-in-progress project. Since it's not in production stage, I'm looking for a free hosting. I've found that heroku offers free plan if using a "single dyno" (heroku gives 750hrs, each month has at most 31*24=744 hours in total). The problem I've found is that regardless of traffic, single dynos go to sleep and, as far as I understood that, you can't change it if using a single dyno only. You need at least 2 dynos, which is paid. And pricing is regardless on traffic.

So is there any free plan to use heroku to deploy a stable app (stable = that is just available)? I don't need scaling.

Comment: Hosting recommendations are off topic here, see the [help].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two resources on how you can use the free New Relic add-on from Heroku (and New Relic, of course) to  keep your single-dyno application active:

[SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480337/easy-way-to-prevent-heroku-idling)

[Coderwall Blog Post on Same Topic](https://coderwall.com/p/u0x3nw)