# Heroku how many apps on a dyno

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm running my blog on an Heroku dyno, and too many times my users have to wait almost half a minute for my blog to respond. There are ways to prevent Heroku from idling: [Easy way to prevent Heroku idling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480337/easy-way-to-prevent-heroku-idling) Most obvious is to ping the server every minute or so.

But it seems those methods are against Heroku's TOS, if I check the pricing page: https://www.heroku.com/pricing (see MUST SLEEP 6 HOURS IN A 24 HOUR PERIOD). And because Pingdom does costs me some money as well, I'm thinking of paying $7 dollars a month for the Hobby package. But how many apps can you run with that package? Cause I always run one app per dyno, but if I have to pay $7 per app... That seems too much.

Anyone who knows there is a way to run multiple apps on a dyno? Or is hiring a server at DigitalOcean with NodeJS a better choice, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free and hobby dyno types only support a maximum of one dyno running per process type. Additionally, applications using a free dyno type are limited to a maximum of two concurrent running dynos.
By default, a process type can’t be scaled to more than 100 dynos for standard-1X or standard-2X sized dynos. A process type can’t be scaled to more than 10 dynos for performance dynos.

Comment: You probably need to quote that copy paste answer from the heroku docs ;) Thanks for the response anyways, but my question was: is there a way to run multiple apps using the Hobby package... Or does the hobby package include my whole account

Comment: Totally a copy and paste but it was more to illustrate the point that what you are trying to achieve can't be done and Heroku points that out in the so said copy and paste.

Comment: Alright thanks. Just contacted Heroku to be 100% clear and like they said: you can run 1 app on the hobby tier with a $7 dyno and another app on the hobby tier with a $7 dyno - so you'd be billed for $14 a month in this example.