# Pinging heroku app during a given time window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Since heroku introduced the new free dynos, it is not possible to keep a dyno awake by pinging it 24/7 anymore. Is there a solution to always keep it alive during a certain timeframe (eg. during business hours) and then leaving it to go to sleep during the night?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480337/easy-way-to-prevent-heroku-idling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a cron job every X minutes (15 or 30 minutes would probably work), and in that cron script check if the current time is within business hours. If so, ping the Heroku app, otherwise don't do anything.