# How to keep my bot active always on slack?

Tags: javascript, slack-api, slack

I used code from GitHub for creating slack, everything was working good, but then my bot status is away, how to keep it active all the time? or at least active when there is at least one active user?

I am using javascript, Heroku server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Heroku's [free tier](https://www.heroku.com/pricing), it will always go to sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity. Heroku has [put measures in place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15325136/5451051) to prevent people from keeping a free tier dyno constantly awake, so the only option is to upgrade your dyno or use a different service.

For the next time you ask a question, keep in mind the [How to Ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to provide more detail on what the actual problem is as this was rather vague.

Comment: yeah, I know that fact. I found out that Heroku does not activate the worker node by default. that why it didn't work