# How to schedule pinging your website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm new to heroku and realized that, with a free dyno, your app idles after 30 minutes of inactivity. I also know that you only get 550 hours of dyno awake-time a month, so I don't want to ping it continuously.

What I'm looking for is a way to keep my application awake for 18 hours a day. As far as I know, the only way to achieve that is by pinging my site, but I cant find a way to ping it only from 8am to 2am. I'm looking for a free option, but I will definitely upgrade my dyno to hobby status once the final app is pushed out.

Any advice on this subject would be greatly appreciated!

ps I looked around, and couldn't find anything about pinging during a specific time period.

Edit: I've seen that New Relic and other sources are able to ping my website, but it seems to me like they ping continuously. While I do want it to be consistent, so that the dyno doesn't fall asleep, I was looking for something that would let me be able to have it ping the site every day in a specified time period! Oh, and I know the easy answer, I don't see what's wrong with taking advantage of the free hours heroku provides me with! I already said that I'm definitely going to upgrade later on.

Comment: I suspect this question is off-topic. However to give you one possible solution is just have a cronjob on your local machine that visits your website periodically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy way to prevent Heroku idling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480337/easy-way-to-prevent-heroku-idling)

Comment: Also, the easy answer if you need it to stay awake is to pay the trivial fee for hobby tier instead of wasting resources trying to freeload